# How does Dropbox generate host_id link

Tags: linux, dropbox, reverse-engineering

I'm studying Dropbox and learning about it's infrastructure. It comes to a scenario when you have just installed dropbox on linux, after running ~/.dropbox-dist/dropboxd you will be given a link in order to link the computer to the account.

The Link has the format: https://www.dropbox.com/cli_link?host_id=xxxxxxxxxx

I'm trying to figure out how dropbox generates those host_id, is it based on the hardware ID or bases on anything?

Please share your ideas if you have one.

Thank you so much.

Comment: You can see it change if you purge the .dropbox directory following each launch. based on an strace, it looks like it uses /dev/urandom as a seed for the data. it reads 16 bytes from this, and while the values do not end up in the host id, the size corresponds to the size of an md5 checksum, so at a wild guess this is how it is done. I don't believe the value is deterministic

Comment: do you think it's unique for each pair (account, device) or it's just a random string ???

Comment: I believe it's a random string. It only has meaning once it's linked to an account

Answer (score 0):

The Host ID is the only parameter that is used for authenticating users and devices. This means that any disclosure of the Host ID will allow an attacker to get access to all the user data in Dropbox. The Host ID is common to all the devices in the specific account and never changes.
These weakness issues have been discussed by information security blogger Derek Newton [3] who also reveals that changing the Dropbox account password would not change the Host ID. So changing password becomes useless.

Reference: http://blog.sikkerhed.alexandra.dk/2012/01/24/cloud-security-a-dropbox-case-study/

It seems Host_ID is generated by Dropbox itself when the user registers their account on dropbox and is never changed in future.

Comment: so I tried to install dropbox on Ubuntu, it generates a link with the host_id. I linked it to a Dropbox account then uninstall dropbox, and all relate misc things. Then I re-install dropbox and run ~/.dropbox-dist/dropboxd again, it generates another host_id which is not the same as before, but actually I can click on the link and link it to the account that I have linked previously. I think it wasn't generated during the register, was it?